# WiFi cycles on and off constantly

Tags: wifi

- 2017 MacBook Air running OS X 10.12.6.
- 1.8 GHz processor
- 8 GB memory

The wifi switches on and off every few seconds: one second on, three or four seconds off. (Note: I *don't* mean that it drops the wifi connection. The wifi *shuts off*, then turns back on.) This has been an intermittent problem for several days, but at first it was only an annoyance: the wifi would switch off briefly, then back on, and everything would be fine. Starting today, though, it's rendered the computer unusable. I have tried the following remedies:

- Restarting
- Disk Utility first aid
- Network Diagnostics (which froze)
- Cycling the router
- Trying to activate the wifi manually using `ifconfig`, as described [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-restart-airport-wireless-from-bash-command-line-in-macosx/amp/).

Other observations:

- The wifi connection on my phone is fine, so I'm inferring that the
  problem is not with the router.
- Activity Monitor shows the `airportd`
  process using 16%-25% of CPU

What is going on here, and how do I fix it?